# How to print all the instances of a class in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, instance

I want to get all the instances created for a class.
Is there any way to get the instances without importing any module ?

I tried this way to append self in a class attribute.

```
class A(object):
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        A.instances.append(self)
        
foo = A("hi")
bar = A("Hey")
star = A("Hero")

for instance in A.instances:
    print("Ins is ",instance)
```

Output

```
<__main__.A object at 0x148b8b6e0780>,
<__main__.A object at 0x148b8b6e0780>,
<__main__.A object at 0x148b8b6e0780>
```

I expect it to print foo,bar,star.
Is there any way to get it in class without any module?

Comment: Suppose you did `baz = foo`. What would you expect it to print then?

Comment: zyou *are* printing the instances of that class. "I expect it to print foo,bar,star. " **why** do you expect that? If I do `x = 1` then `print(x)`, does it print `x` or `1` to the screen?

Comment: In general, you should be providing the data an object should know about to it explicitly, usually as an argument to the constructor (a fancy name for this is *dependency injection*). If you want an object to know about `"foo"`, then *pass in that string*. Then you can modify the default printing behavior for that type by implementing `__repr__` and/or `__str__`.

Comment: Also note that you may create instances without ever bind them to a name, e.g. in a list comprehension. Your object shouldn't care about the name it is bind to. The opposite suggest there is probably design problem.

Comment: If you want to rely on variable names, you'd have to go through various hijinks like those seen in [this library](https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname) (note, it's a pretty good read if you want to understand python internals, and how you'd do it). But really, truly, you should *simply [keep data out of variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)*. The long and the short of it is, while it's an interesting exercise to see how this could be done, you generally should not design your code around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do the following, if I got you right :

**Proposal**

```
tmp = globals().copy()
print(tmp)

for k,v in tmp.items():
    if isinstance(v, A):
        print(k)
```

You must copy the global variable dictionary, because otherwise i will be changed with the first instantiation in the for-loop:

**Result:**

```
foo
bar
star
```

Comment: This won't work everywhere. See info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet:

```
for instance in A.instances:
    print("Ins is ", (instance.__dict__).get("foo"))
```

Output:

```
Ins is  hi
Ins is  Hey
Ins is  Hero
```

Or:

```
for instance in A.instances:
    print("Ins is ", instance.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
Ins is  {'foo': 'hi'}
Ins is  {'foo': 'Hey'}
Ins is  {'foo': 'Hero'}
```

To print an object, you can turn it into a dictionary. In this case, these values will be printable.

This method is usually used to convert objects to a dictionary and then to the JSON type, which is widely used to exchange information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define such behavior in a class, because the class assigns a value to a variable after instantiation. There is no way to get the name of the variable during class instantiation, because the variable does not exist yet